# How to implement Ping federate in ASP.NET Core 6 using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

It's the first time that I want to use ping federate into C# ASP.NET core 6 but I couldn't find any sample or NuGet Package in this regard.
The only useful guide that i could find, belonged to older version of ASP, which was not supported by ASP.NET Core 6:
(I need sth like the below guide)

https://github.com/amd989/Owin.Security.Providers.PingFederate

Is there anyone who might have this experience?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ping publishes [a sample application built with dotnet core](https://github.com/pingidentity/pf-agentless-ik-sample-dotnet-core) that use the Ping Federate Agentless Integration Kit a.k.a. the reference ID adapter.

The ["Agentless SP Sample"](https://github.com/pingidentity/pf-agentless-ik-sample-dotnet-core/tree/master/sample-applications/AgentlessSpSample) project is most likely what you are looking for as it is a simple web page with a button that says 'Click to Single Sign On'.